# Changing HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: https, http

I am trying to change my site from HTTP to HTTPS, I read a article where you change the site url in your wordpress setting from http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com . After I do this, I get a 440 error.

Please if anyone can help getting my site to HTTPS.

Regards

Raymond

Comment: but have you enabled https in your hosting?

Comment: what article you read?

Comment: HTTP Status Code 440: "The client's session has expired and must log in again"